# Mode of Bing Maps - change posiotion

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, windows-store-apps

Can I change position of the box where I can choose the mode of Bing Maps ?

[image]

or how I can collapsed this box ?

Answer (score 0):

[This helps you to collapse the NavigationBar!](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bingmapswindows8/thread/a647e305-a05e-4cf8-a33b-13e4388dbfba/) It says that you should set `ShowNavigationBar` to false. You can do this in the xaml.

I am not aware of how you could change the position of the NavigationBar.